# Is there a better way to check if a STL container is a multi* container

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl, traits

During my work on writing a unit test for a framework that shall work with all kind of standard C++11 container I stepped over the problem that I want to create in a generic way test data.
Here I need to know if an associated container C is a multi* container. Eg. if C is a std::set or a std::multiset. I searched through the interface of all of these containers and all of them have in common that they have an insert(value_type const&) method. But from my point of view the significant difference is that the multi* version returns just an iterator, but the 'non' multi* version return a std::pair. So I choose this as differentiator.

My resulting code is:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename Container>
class is_multi_container
{
  typedef typename Container::value_type T;
  typedef typename Container::iterator ExpectedType;
  typedef decltype(Container().insert(T())) ResultType;
public:
  static const bool value = std::is_same<ResultType, ExpectedType>::value;
};

#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
  std::cout << "std::set<T> is " << is_multi_container<std::set<int>>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << "std::multiset<T> is " << is_multi_container<std::multiset<int>>::value << std::endl;

  std::cout << "std::map<K,T> is " << is_multi_container<std::map<int,double>>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << "std::multimap<K,T> is " << is_multi_container<std::multimap<int,double>>::value << std::endl;

  std::cout << "std::unordered_set<T> is " << is_multi_container<std::unordered_set<int>>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << "std::unordered_multiset<T> is " << is_multi_container<std::unordered_multiset<int>>::value << std::endl;

  std::cout << "std::unordered_map<K,T> is " << is_multi_container<std::unordered_map<int,double>>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << "std::unordered_multimap<K,T> is " << is_multi_container<std::unordered_multimap<int,double>>::value << std::endl;
}
```

According to this small test program, it seems to work, but I am not sure if a) this solutions has problems that I do not see so far and b) if there is a more elegant way to write such a trait? I am aware that the trait only works with associative container.

Many thanks in advance!

PS.: I have to work with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: This looks pretty good! More elegant, you say?

Comment: you can use typeid().name() from <typeinfo> header and check if it contains the word multi in it

Comment: The `typename` before `decltype` is not necessary (I needed to remove it to compile on gcc).

Comment: prajmus, typeid().name() is RTTI, which has a runtime cost, this is a compile-time test.

Comment: You can't use typeid().name() without parsing it, because it could be a set<multiset<U>> (for instance)

Comment: `std::type_info::name()` returns an implementation-defined string, there is no guarantee it contains "multi"

Comment: Your solution is what I would have done, testing the return type of `insert` is a great way to distinguish it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing as there are a small finite number of `std::multi*` containers, you can just list them:

```
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>

#include <type_traits>

template <typename Container>
struct is_multi_container :
    std::false_type
{};

template <typename T, typename Compare, typename Alloc>
struct is_multi_container<std::multiset<T, Compare, Alloc>> :
    std::true_type
{};

template <typename T, typename Compare, typename Alloc>
struct is_multi_container<std::multimap<T, Compare, Alloc>> :
    std::true_type
{};

template <typename T, typename Compare, typename Alloc>
struct is_multi_container<std::unordered_multiset<T, Compare, Alloc>> :
    std::true_type
{};

template <typename T, typename Compare, typename Alloc>
struct is_multi_container<std::unordered_multimap<T, Compare, Alloc>> :
    std::true_type
{};
```

More lines of code, but it's easy to read and is direct in its reasoning (i.e., it definitely works!).

Being an explicit list, the caveat is that it doesn't extend itself automatically. For that, your solution is good. C++14 may have an `AssociativeContainer` concept which would make this even easier; research on this is left as an exercise for the reader. ;)

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    #define TEST(type, ...)                                     \
            std::cout << type " is: "                           \
                      << is_multi_container<__VA_ARGS__>::value \
                      << std::endl

    TEST("std::set<T>", std::set<int>);
    TEST("std::multiset<T>", std::multiset<int>);

    TEST("std::map<K,T>", std::map<int, double>);
    TEST("std::multimap<K,T>", std::multimap<int, double>);

    TEST("std::unordered_set<T>", std::unordered_set<int>);
    TEST("std::unordered_multiset<T>", std::unordered_multiset<int>);

    TEST("std::unordered_map<K,T>", std::unordered_map<int, double>);
    TEST("std::unordered_multimap<K,T>", std::unordered_multimap<int, double>);
}
```

Output:

```
std::set<T> is: false
std::multiset<T> is: true
std::map<K,T> is: false
std::multimap<K,T> is: true
std::unordered_set<T> is: false
std::unordered_multiset<T> is: true
std::unordered_map<K,T> is: false
std::unordered_multimap<K,T> is: true
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I had something similar comparing to your idea in mind. I see the advantage of your solution, because the traits "speak" more what they mean. But I was looking for a more elegant solution that is readable and shorter.

Comment: @FelixPetriconi: Shorter doesn't really imply readable, and tricky doesn't imply elegant. It's not like you're going to stare at it everyday once you've completed it. Stuff this into "is_multi_container.hpp" and never look at it again.

Comment: Nice. Could you tackle the duplication with a typelist?

Comment: In theory the Associative Container requirements apply to more types than just the standard containers, so the OP's solution is more generic and would work with third-party containers meeting the same concepts, e.g. from Boost.Container

Comment: @PeterWood: Which duplication? :)

Comment: @PeterWood, a typelist might remove duplication, but would probably make the code several times longer. A small amount of somewhat repetitive code could be simpler, easier to maintain and faster to compile than a solution using a typelist

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I thought of that but that title says STL container (stdlib, I took it as), so I didn't concern myself with it.

Comment: Another valid interpretation would be "meeting the STL concepts", which applies to the std::lib containers _and_ other similar ones :)  +1 anyway for a working solution

Comment: @GManNickG You have 4 chunks of code, each of 4 lines, and the only difference between them is `multiset`, `multimap`, `unordered_multiset`, and `unordered_multimap`. (c:

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Ah, fair enough. :) I'll add a note.

Comment: @PeterWood: Ah. I'd use a macro for that if I really wanted, but like I said in my first comment, you only write it once.

Comment: I would suggest that you avoid guessing, but declare a trait template that you specialize for all associative containers in the standard library. That way, a new container will not assume either trait but simply cause a compile error.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: I'm not sure I follow, what guessing?

Comment: Sorry, my wording was bad. What I wanted to suggest was to declare a trait template without providing a default implementation. Instead, I would provide a specialization for all containers that either derives from true_type or false_type. Since there's only a handful of them, this isn't that much work, but it saves confusion when adding a new container.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: I'm not sure I see the advantage. By definition, a type is not a `std::multi*` container unless it fits the small list. I don't get what you mean by adding a new container.

Comment: Well, if I write my own container, your type traits will claim that it's not a multi*-container although it doesn't know anything about it. I would prefer if your traits caused a compile error instead. However, if you decide that you want to restrict your code to what is currently in the C++ standard, then your implementation fits those requirements.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: Right, as stated in the answer (and in the comments above) this checks if a given type is a `std::multi*` container, per the title question. That is, if your given type isn't in the standard library then don't bother asking. Jonathan and I agree the given code in the question is a solid approach to determining if a type meets the Associative Container concept, which is what you are worried about.