# Distingushing STL containers

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, containers

Quite frequently, I want to specialize a function for different STL containers. However I don't want to specialize one by one, since some of them share most of the needed interfaces, e.g, std::vector and std::deque.

In my use cases, there are mostly three categories( vector-like, set-like, map-like ).
For example, I want to implement something like,

```
template <class T>
struct A {
    template <class Y, class... Z>
    void func( Y y , Z... z ){
        //hypothetical static_if
        static_if ( T is similar to vector, deque, or boost::stable_vector etc which have push_back ) {
            t.push_back(y);
        }
        else static_if ( T is similar to set, unordered_set or boost::flat_set etc which have emplace)    {
            t.emplace(y);
        }

        else static_if ( T is similar to map, unordered_map or boost::flat_map etc which has emplace) {
            t.emplace(y, z...);
        }

    }

    T t;  
};
```

I think this seems impossible but I hope there is some kind of hack for this situation. 
It would be also good if it can be extended to the list types(std::list, std::forward_list, ...) or boost::heap or else. However it seems too difficult to achieve the goal.

Comment: What *is* the goal? In which circumstances are vectors, sets and maps interchangeable?

Comment: You can create type traits and have one function specialization for each xxx-like type.

Comment: This can be done suing specialization and type traits but it seems like your reinventing the wheel since a lot of functionality is provide by the std algos with generic interfaces

Comment: @larsmans: Now I am implementing adjacency list for graph. the second container for storing neighbors of edges can be vectors or sets or maps in my project.

Comment: There is an overload of insert() that works for anything, maybe use that.

Comment: @rerun: So which functionality should I look at for this purpose?

Comment: @Mehrdad: All of them have `insert()` function. But their function signitures are different. How can I use them generically?

Comment: Scott Meyers, Effective STL, has full section devoted to telling you not to do this.

Comment: By "vector-like" you mean sequential random-access.  Map and set are associative containers.  (Read Meyers' book.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a crude type traits library for containers.

```
template<typename Container>
struct container_traits;

template<bool b=true>
struct has_emplace_back { typedef std::integral_constant<bool, b> emplace_back; };
template<bool b=true>
struct has_emplace { typedef std::integral_constant<bool, b> emplace; };

template<typename T, typename A>
struct container_traits< std::vector<T,A> > : has_emplace_back<>, has_emplace<> {};
// etc
template<typename T, typename A>
struct container_traits< std::set<T,A> > : has_emplace_back<false>, has_emplace<> {};
// etc

template<typename T>
using HasEmplaceBack = typename container_traits<T>::has_emplace_back;
template<typename T>
using HasEmplace = typename container_traits<T>::has_emplace;

template<int> struct enum_enum { enum class type {}; };
template<int index> using UniqueEnum = typename enum_enum<index>::type;

template<bool b, int index=1>
using EnableIf = typename std::enable_if< UniqueEnum<index> >::type;
template<bool b, int index=1>
using DisableIf = EnableIf< b, -index >;

template<typename Container, typename... Args, EnableIf< HasEmplace<Container>::value && !HasEmplaceBack<Container>::value, 1 >... >
void emplace_in( Container&& c, Args&&... args ) {
  std::forward<Container>(c).emplace( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
}
template<typename Container, typename... Args, EnableIf< HasEmplaceBack<Container>::value, 2 >... >
void emplace_in( Container&& c, Args&&... args ) {
  std::forward<Container>(c).emplace_back( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
}
```

The `EnableIf<>...` technique does not work in clang, and I didn't compile it so it probably requires some debugging to fix.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I cannot fully understand your code especially for UniqueEnum. Anyway, I guess std::vector has both emplace and emplace_back.

Comment: @Sungmin Good point -- although that `emplace` is different.  "Has location-free emplace" is wordy.  `UniqueEnum<x>` is a distinct empty `enum class` type for each `x`, `EnableIf` and `DisableIf` evaluate to such `UniqueEnum` types if `bool` is true.  I pass (empty) variadic packs of these `UniqueEnum` to `emplace_in` as type parameters to ensure that the two `template`s have distinct `template` signatures.  I'll fix up the container traits a tad to make the false case work...

Comment: Thanks. It seems quite nifty trick.:) So, I have to enumerate all possible containers as a template parameter in `container_trait` right?

Comment: @sungmin emplace without arguments cannot be detected.  Emplace with arguments can be.  So a trait `can_emplace_back_with<T,Args...>` could be written, together with `can_emplace_nakedly`.  That is a bit dangerous, because if `Args...` happens to be 2 or more long, and the first arg is convertable to `iterator`, you could get an unexpected `emplace` working on a `vector`.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, sorry. Don't do it.  A full section in Scott Meyers' *Effective STL* is devoted to this.  Here is an excerpt to give you an idea of how problematic this is:

> Suppose, then, you aspire to write code that can be used with the
>   most common sequence containers: vector, deque, and list. Clearly,
>   you must program to the intersection of their capabilities, and that
>   means no uses of reserve or capacity (see Item 14), because deque and
>   list don’t offer them. The presence of list also means you give up operator[], and you limit yourself to the capabilities of bidirectional iterators. That, in turn, means you must stay away from algorithms that
>   demand random access iterators, including sort, stable_sort,
>   partial_sort, and nth_element (see Item 31).
>
> On the other hand, your desire to support vector rules out use of
>   push_front and pop_front, and both vector and deque put the kibosh on
>   splice and the member form of sort. In conjunction with the constraints above, this latter prohibition means that there is no form of
>   sort you can call on your “generalized sequence container.”
>
> That’s the obvious stuff. If you violate any of those restrictions, your
>   code will fail to compile with at least one of the containers you want to
>   be able to use. The code that will compile is more insidious.
>
> The main culprit is the different rules for invalidation of iterators,
>   pointers, and references that apply to different sequence containers.
>   To write code that will work correctly with vector, deque, and list, you
>   must assume that any operation invalidating iterators, pointers, or
>   references in any of those containers invalidates them in the container
>   you’re using. Thus, you must assume that every call to insert invalidates everything, because deque::insert invalidates all iterators and,
>   lacking the ability to call capacity, vector::insert must be assumed to
>   invalidate all pointers and references. (Item 1 explains that deque is
>   unique in sometimes invalidating its iterators without invalidating its
>   pointers and references.) Similar reasoning leads to the conclusion
>   that every call to erase must be assumed to invalidate everything.
>
> Want more? [yes, this item goes on, and on, and on.]

Answer (score 0):

It's not impossible, it's just not convenient or trivial to implement.  Really, there needs to be a `container_traits` library.

This could be implemented using **[SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE)** to detect if a certain type `Container` contains the necessary features to meet the requirements of various STL [Container Concepts](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Container.html).

For example, `is_associative_container` could use SFINAE to check that the `Container` type has a `key_type` and `mapped_type` typedef, and a `std::pair<const key_type, map_type>` for `value_type`, along with all the other requirements for an object that implements the `AssociativeContainer` concept.

Anyway, this is really something that needs to be implemented as a fully-fledged library.  It's not trivial to implement, and you should probably look for another solution if you have a simple one-time need.  You'd be better off abstracting at the `Iterator` level.

Comment: So, isn't there a well-known library which has something similar to `is_associative_container`?

Comment: There doesn't need to be a container_traits library.  Its lack of existence in part discourages bad design, like the design proposed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried sofisticated traits a week ago, but went for a better readability.

So see here an examples: [Is there a better way to check if a STL container is a multi* container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993567/is-there-a-better-way-to-check-if-a-stl-container-is-a-multi-container?noredirect=1#comment24553218_16993567)

Comment: Thanks, so you are suggesting that I have to specialize all possible classes? I guess it seems the most clean way.

Comment: That depends on what characteristica you have to go for. In my case I had to distinguish the groups set, map and multi...